# Efficient sorting and ranking of long list of 2d lists in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, ranking

I have a dataset with several hundred 2d value plots stored in list such as   this simplified version (actual plots are up to 100 x 100):

```
[['p01',               ['p0x',
 [[30, 40, 50]         [[42, 52, 72]
  [33, 43, 53]          [44, 63, 83]
  [36, 46, 56]]],...    [76, 96, 99]]
```

I have so far iterated through the plots to simply check if the current plot has the lowest value for a cell and then stored the lowest costs and lowest plots name into the respective result array, giving me two array like so:
*lowest values*

```
[[20, 40, 45]
 [26, 42, 50]
 [36, 44, 51]]]
```

*lowest plot for each point*

```
[[p02, p01, p03]
 [p02, p02, p02]
 [p01, p01, p04]]]
```

What I ideally like is say the lowest 10 of each, i.e. is there an efficient way to go through the plots without having to iterate through loop by loop
i.e.: generate lowest, iterate again and see if 2nd lowest (is higher then lowest but lower than currently stored in 2nd lowest array) etc

Comment: Are you working with *lists* or *arrays*? They are not synonymous. Also, can you clarify what you want, exactly, as the output... 20 arrays like the two you gave above, each pair of ascending rank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's a plain, brute-force Python solution. I don't think it's the very efficient (I believe it's O(n^3log(n)), but it *works*:

Suppose, we have some data like the following:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(data)
[['p1',
  [[48, 71, 36, 40, 80, 59],
   [44, 56, 87, 43, 78, 47],
   [45, 71, 86, 61, 45, 27],
   [40, 82, 72, 39, 47, 77],
   [46, 82, 66, 48, 78, 57],
   [49, 38, 65, 56, 75, 79]]],
 ['p2',
  [[82, 49, 72, 76, 48, 67],
   [78, 57, 62, 20, 43, 28],
   [71, 40, 23, 35, 88, 32],
   [51, 66, 73, 84, 68, 35],
   [44, 42, 44, 67, 20, 59],
   [62, 20, 39, 33, 63, 46]]],
 ['p3',
  [[70, 59, 86, 80, 70, 87],
   [88, 47, 38, 63, 56, 63],
   [84, 26, 46, 31, 52, 22],
   [51, 63, 63, 34, 58, 87],
   [75, 69, 39, 37, 88, 35],
   [42, 25, 76, 86, 59, 47]]],
 ['p4',
  [[44, 21, 39, 57, 61, 88],
   [31, 64, 36, 42, 79, 62],
   [41, 38, 21, 82, 71, 60],
   [37, 23, 46, 40, 77, 69],
   [27, 47, 64, 59, 51, 32],
   [23, 68, 76, 67, 39, 60]]],
 ['p5',
  [[33, 41, 41, 54, 25, 86],
   [64, 34, 76, 66, 78, 51],
   [85, 47, 85, 22, 40, 28],
   [20, 33, 30, 59, 86, 47],
   [36, 39, 32, 60, 41, 78],
   [57, 33, 35, 37, 86, 64]]],
 ['p6',
  [[58, 72, 82, 80, 80, 21],
   [41, 45, 57, 67, 74, 39],
   [70, 78, 51, 81, 85, 86],
   [81, 53, 49, 73, 60, 60],
   [26, 66, 60, 38, 87, 54],
   [31, 55, 44, 38, 28, 68]]],
 ['p7',
  [[43, 22, 57, 66, 53, 68],
   [65, 61, 52, 78, 59, 27],
   [66, 42, 58, 79, 75, 60],
   [83, 81, 67, 43, 34, 76],
   [53, 41, 36, 34, 32, 76],
   [68, 43, 53, 46, 54, 41]]],
 ['p8',
  [[74, 65, 37, 50, 51, 87],
   [72, 79, 65, 44, 46, 73],
   [42, 31, 80, 46, 63, 24],
   [83, 40, 28, 39, 86, 29],
   [29, 45, 86, 20, 26, 25],
   [52, 52, 34, 24, 44, 65]]],
 ['p9',
  [[63, 76, 54, 71, 64, 56],
   [24, 30, 67, 65, 49, 50],
   [38, 40, 55, 72, 78, 56],
   [74, 41, 34, 62, 53, 76],
   [30, 30, 36, 86, 69, 74],
   [40, 87, 29, 75, 50, 51]]]]
```

First, we sort each `i, j` value *along the first axis*:

```
>>> def matrix_idx(x,y, matrix):
...     return matrix[x][y]
...
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorts = [[sorted([(tag, matrix_idx(i, j, matrix)) for tag, matrix in data], key=itemgetter(1)) for j in range(6)] for i in range(6)]
```

So, now, each element of `sorts`:

```
>>> pprint(sorts[0], width=600)
[[('p5', 33), ('p7', 43), ('p4', 44), ('p1', 48), ('p6', 58), ('p9', 63), ('p3', 70), ('p8', 74), ('p2', 82)],
 [('p4', 21), ('p7', 22), ('p5', 41), ('p2', 49), ('p3', 59), ('p8', 65), ('p1', 71), ('p6', 72), ('p9', 76)],
 [('p1', 36), ('p8', 37), ('p4', 39), ('p5', 41), ('p9', 54), ('p7', 57), ('p2', 72), ('p6', 82), ('p3', 86)],
 [('p1', 40), ('p8', 50), ('p5', 54), ('p4', 57), ('p7', 66), ('p9', 71), ('p2', 76), ('p3', 80), ('p6', 80)],
 [('p5', 25), ('p2', 48), ('p8', 51), ('p7', 53), ('p4', 61), ('p9', 64), ('p3', 70), ('p1', 80), ('p6', 80)],
 [('p6', 21), ('p9', 56), ('p1', 59), ('p2', 67), ('p7', 68), ('p5', 86), ('p3', 87), ('p8', 87), ('p4', 88)]]
>>> len(sorts)
6
>>>
>>> len(sorts[0])
6
```

What does this correspond to? Consider again:

```
[['p1',
  [[48, 71, **36**, 40, 80, 59],
   [44, 56, 87, 43, 78, 47],
   [45, 71, 86, 61, 45, 27],
   [40, 82, 72, 39, 47, 77],
   [46, 82, 66, 48, 78, 57],
   [49, 38, 65, 56, 75, 79]]],
...

['p4',
  [[44, **21**, 39, 57, 61, 88],
   [31, 64, 36, 42, 79, 62],
   [41, 38, 21, 82, 71, 60],
   [37, 23, 46, 40, 77, 69],
   [27, 47, 64, 59, 51, 32],
   [23, 68, 76, 67, 39, 60]]],
 ['p5',
  [[**33**, 41, 41, 54, 25, 86],
   [64, 34, 76, 66, 78, 51],
   [85, 47, 85, 22, 40, 28],
   [20, 33, 30, 59, 86, 47],
   [36, 39, 32, 60, 41, 78],
   [57, 33, 35, 37, 86, 64]]],
```

So each ith element of `sorts` contains a list, with the sorted values for the ith row, going *down the first axis* of the `data`. So, let's do one final transformation to get this into a more useful format, first, let's define a handy `namedtuple`:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Data = namedtuple('Data', 'origin value')
```

Now, finally:

```
>>> for r in range(len(data)):
...     val = []
...     orig = []
...     for i in range(6):
...         orig.append([sorts[i][j][r][0] for j in range(6)])
...         val.append([sorts[i][j][r][1] for j in range(6)])
...     ranked.append(Data(orig, val))
...
```

And now, check this:

```
>>> pprint(ranked[0].value)
[[33, 21, 36, 40, 25, 21],
 [24, 30, 36, 20, 43, 27],
 [38, 26, 21, 22, 40, 22],
 [20, 23, 28, 34, 34, 29],
 [26, 30, 32, 20, 20, 25],
 [23, 20, 29, 24, 28, 41]]
>>> pprint(ranked[0].origin)
[['p5', 'p4', 'p1', 'p1', 'p5', 'p6'],
 ['p9', 'p9', 'p4', 'p2', 'p2', 'p7'],
 ['p9', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p5', 'p3'],
 ['p5', 'p4', 'p8', 'p3', 'p7', 'p8'],
 ['p6', 'p9', 'p5', 'p8', 'p2', 'p8'],
 ['p4', 'p2', 'p9', 'p8', 'p6', 'p7']]
>>> pprint(ranked[-1].value)
[[82, 76, 86, 80, 80, 88],
 [88, 79, 87, 78, 79, 73],
 [85, 78, 86, 82, 88, 86],
 [83, 82, 73, 84, 86, 87],
 [75, 82, 86, 86, 88, 78],
 [68, 87, 76, 86, 86, 79]]
>>> pprint(ranked[-1].origin)
[['p2', 'p9', 'p3', 'p6', 'p6', 'p4'],
 ['p3', 'p8', 'p1', 'p7', 'p4', 'p8'],
 ['p5', 'p6', 'p1', 'p4', 'p2', 'p6'],
 ['p8', 'p1', 'p2', 'p2', 'p8', 'p3'],
 ['p3', 'p1', 'p8', 'p9', 'p3', 'p5'],
 ['p7', 'p9', 'p4', 'p3', 'p5', 'p1']]
```

Whether it is performant enough for your use-case I don't know, but it sure was fun!

Answer (score 1):

If you have NumPy (you tagged it with [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays) so I assume you already work with NumPy) you could use [`np.min`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html#numpy.minimum) and [`np.argmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) to get the lowest and index of the lowest element:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> p1 = [[1, 10], 
...       [1, 20]]
>>> p2 = [[2, 8],
...       [4, 6]]
>>> p3 = [[0, 4],
...       [17, 8]]

>>> np.min([p1, p2, p3], axis=0)      # lowest value
array([[0, 4],
       [1, 6]])

>>> np.argmin([p1, p2, p3], axis=0)   # lowest plot number
array([[2, 2],
       [0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

In case you want to sort them you can use `np.sort` and `np.argsort`:

```
>>> np.sort([p1, p2, p3], axis=0)
array([[[ 0,  4],          # lowest
        [ 1,  6]],

       [[ 1,  8],          # middle
        [ 4,  8]],

       [[ 2, 10],          # highest
        [17, 20]]])

>>> np.argsort([p1, p2, p3], axis=0)
array([[[2, 2],
        [0, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 0],
        [2, 0]]], dtype=int64)
```